# CookieContainer (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

How can I store a CookieContainer as a global variable, not inside of a function?

Comment: Welcome to SO Ovidiu. When you say "as a global variable", to help us answer, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If by *global* you mean *static* you could use the [Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Shared Container As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer();

    ...
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in an application variable.

```
Dim CookieJar as new CookieContainer()
Application.Add("MyCookieJar", CookieJar)
```